# How to geocode a Twitter status update using the Ruby OAuth Gem

Tags: ruby, twitter, geocoding, twitter-oauth

Using the following Ruby code, I can send a status update over the Twitter API to my account. According to the [Twitter API Docs](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/update) I would expect it to be geocoded, but it isn't. What am I doing wrong?

```
require 'oauth'
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new('<MY_CONSUMER_KEY>', '<MY_CONSUMER_SECRET>', :site => "http://api.twitter.com", :scheme => :header)
access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(consumer, :oauth_token => '<MY_OAUTH_TOKEN>', :oauth_token_secret => '<MY_OAUTH_SECRET>')
access_token.request(:post, "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.xml", {"Content-Type" => "application/xml", "status" => "This Tweet is from Zuerich in Switzerland", "lat" => "47.3807", "long" => "8.537", "display_coordinates" => "true", "geo_enabled" => "true"})
```

Comment: it works ok for me. is "Add a location to your tweets" enabled in your twitter profile settings?

Comment: @nash: Thanks a lot, that was the solution! :)

Comment: @nash: Put that in an answer and I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works ok. You should enable `"Add a location to your tweets"` in your twitter profile settings.